# Can I install Drupal on a server with 256MB ram?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Can I install Drupal on a server with 256MB ram ?

If yes, how many Drupal websites ? The server is supposed to only run such websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I install Drupal on a server with
>   256MB ram ?

No problem. Take a Debian GNU/Linux minimal install. Add apache2, php and mysql. Install drupal, You are done.

> If yes, how many Drupal websites ?

As much as fit on your disk drives.

All other depends on what modules you need, the request load, the response payload, etc.

Comment: I've actually installed Ubuntu with the minimum Apache2, php and mysql but I get many times the "Out of memory" message. Do I need to uninstall something... ?

Comment: @Patrick: it would be helpful if you could add that message to your question. Consider adding more swap space. What's the output of the `free` command?

Answer (score 1):

**Exact same question**

- [Can drupal run on a Debian Linux vserver with 256MB?](http://drupal.org/node/68341)

Drupal need a LAMP server, lamp can be of any configuration min-max, number sites depend your safe available HDD space.

But i think. its enough to run server to host drupal sites.

Comment: ok thanks...I'm actually getting many times "Out of memory" error. Do I need to uninstall something... ? I've just installed the minimal installation Apache2, PHP5, Mysql on Ubuntu 9.04

Comment: it doesnt be when the article was from, if its valid till the date.

Comment: what should I exactly adjust there ? I've already set memory_limit parameter to 128MB. This is what you meant ?

Comment: dont feed all your memory for drupal script only. try checking which program is eating memory, if you are using ubuntu , use command top to check that.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal is very processor intensive in my experience. RAM is generally not an issue. I use a shared hosting server with 32 MB RAM to run the latest version of Drupal.

You might be running into problems because of using PHP settings. Try adding `memory_limit = 128M` to your php.ini file.

If you are still facing problems, then you'd have to find out which modules are eating up your RAM and disable them. If a single module is doing this, then it may be buggy, so you are better off without it.

Comment: i've already set to 128M. Indeed I don't get any warning from php. I can see the Apache server error message in the shell: "Out of memory". I've just installed apache+php+mysql on a Ubuntu. Standard installation. Trust me, the drupal website has not heavy modules, it run perfectly on other servers (Just moved).

Answer (score 1):

The solution was not about Drupal configuration but Apache configuration.

I had to change these MPM parameters:

http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/5/19/configuring-the-apache-mpm-on-ubuntu